# How to get the value of current selected date from calendar eonasdan

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar

I am using http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ for calendar. Now I want to pick the selected date by the user. I am stuck with this calendar. Please help me to get the current selected date by the user I have used js to get the value.

On each date there is a class named "day". Now I wanted to get the value of the attribute "data-day" which have the value of the date as follows:

```
$(".day").click(function(){
            var clicked = $(this).attr('id');
         alert(clicked);
         });
```

It returns the attribute's value only one time it's not recognizing the second click.

Please help me with js or this eonasdan plugin.

Comment: Here is the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/0Ltv25o8/
but they have used only the input filed and not the calendar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML

```
<br/>
<!-- padding for jsfiddle -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker2" />
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="getDate" value="Get Date" />
    </div>
         <span id="SelectedDate"></span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();

$('#getDate').click(function () {
    console.log($('#datetimepicker2').data('date'))
    $('#SelectedDate').text($('#datetimepicker2').data('date'))
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/santoshj/0Ltv25o8/1736/)
[Get Only Date Part](http://jsfiddle.net/santoshj/0Ltv25o8/1737/)

Comment: Can you please help to get only date not the current time?

Comment: i wanted to get date along with month and year.

Comment: the `temp` variable in the second fiddle  consists date. check this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp . i just showed to get date only. you try others (month and year).

Comment: @J Santosh How i will disable the time less than current time

Comment: @TausifAnwar use this     $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(new Date());

Comment: The fiddles no longer function

Answer (score 1):

I have found methods for calendar described at linked page.
So for example to see what have user entered you have to:

```
$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date()
```

input here your id and as result receive object which has '_d' field with value.

```
data('DateTimePicker')
```

also has a lot of taste functions to configure plugin.

Comment: data('date') takes result faster.

Answer (score 0):

i think i might have the solution for you.

```
$('#datetimepicker1').data('date')
```

Please have a go.

Comment: will you please help me where to put this code?
i mean should i put this code in my own function?

Comment: yeah. @TausifAnwar  you can add this into your function .. so you just have to save it to the variable      `var selectedDate = $('#datetimepicker1').data('date');`  simple as that.. now you could use that variable for your use